# Configuring Plexus Logging

Tags: java, logging, plexus

I have a library that uses Plexus Logging facilities. My project configures it's own logging through slf4j with slf4j-simple.

I've tried to mute the logging in the library through `simplelogger.properties` using

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.com.acme.lib=off
```

This had no effect.

Debugging into the culprit class, I found that it's injected a `org.codehaus.plexus.logging.Logger`. Whenever I get my component from the container, that `Logger` is an `org.codehaus.plexus.logging.console.ConsoleLogger`.

I tried to bind my own NoOp implementation of the logger for injection like so:

```
PlexusContainer container = new DefaultPlexusContainer();
// other components
// remove all Logger components
container.releaseAll(container.lookupList(Logger.class));
container.addComponent(new NoOpLogger(), Logger.class, "default");
```

But that did not have an effect on the actually injected logger instance.
I **was** able to obtain my Logger implementation from the container using `container.lookup(Logger.class)`, but the component still used it's `ConsoleLogger`.

To remedy that I tried to register a `LoggerManager` that'd construct my logger implementations like so:

```
// code from above, and additionally
container.releaseAll(container.lookupList(LoggerManager.class));
container.addComponent(new NoOpLoggerManager(), LoggerManager.class, "default");
```

While I now can also obtain my `LoggerManager` from the container, still the `ConsoleLogger` is injected to the Library's component.

How can I make sure my `NoOpLogger` is injected into the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Logger` implementations injected by `DefaultPlexusContainer` are not obtained by looking them up from the components.

Instead you need to bind the LoggerManager through [`DefaultPlexusContainer#setLoggerManager`](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-containers/plexus-container-default/apidocs/org/codehaus/plexus/DefaultPlexusContainer.html#setLoggerManager(org.codehaus.plexus.logging.LoggerManager)) like this:

```
DefaultPlexusContainer container = new DefaultPlexusContainer();
container.setLoggerManager(new NoOpLoggerManager());
// other components
```